# OpenModelica svg icon for blocks

Tags: svg, openmodelica

The svg icon of a block is not displayed. Here's how I set it:

- I switch to Icon view
- Click on Bitmap
- Draw a rectangle
- In Bitmap properties I select the svg file through Browse (the option for svgs exists). The svg file is in the same folder as the .mo file.
- Click Ok and the svg icon is not displayed - I get nothing (like a white icon - I can only see the corners of the bitmap rectangle). The svg file was created in Inkscape and saved as Plain svg.

Is this svg icon option not implemented yet but will be in the near future? or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The svg option was there by mistake. The supported formats for bitmap are PNG, BMP and JPEG. I have fixed it now in r18662.

Adeel.